# Spring boot POST PDF Content type 'application/pdf not supported

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to have a backend where I send two PDF's and work with those. For that I have to implement a REST service but I'm not able to receive them.

PostMapping

```
@PostMapping("/post")
    CompareJob compareJob(@RequestBody File file1) {
        System.out.print("Received File: " + file1);
        CompareJob compareJob = new CompareJob();
        return compareJob;
    }
```

To do the POST requests I use Postman where I've set following things:

Headers -> Content-Type: application/pdf

Body -> Binary: testPDF.pdf

This is the response I'm getting:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-12T13:55:12.898+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/post"
}
```

I'm very new to REST services and would greatly appreciate some hints what is wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Edit after amin10043 suggestion:

```
@PostMapping("/post")
    CompareJob compareJob(@RequestParam("file1") MultipartFile file1) {
        System.out.print("Received File: " + file1);
        CompareJob compareJob = new CompareJob();
        return compareJob;
    }
```

After reading I should not check Content-Type in Postman I'm getting this response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-12T14:37:52.765+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Current request is not a multipart request",
    "path": "/post"
}
```

My fault was that I uploaded the pdf as a binary and not as form-data in postman. Must be set like this: https://snag.gy/H4w5S8.jpg

Comment: Content-Type should be application/octet-stream

Comment: Thanks for your response but the message now is: "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8' not supported",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload files it's better to use [Multipartfile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html), Also please change your input parameter from `@RequesBody` to `@RequestParam("your parameter name")`, in that way postman add correct headers to the request and is should work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I tried to follow. Please see my edit to see the new error. Thanks

Comment: please check your postman and remove all things in request header part, it should be empty and it detects the correct header type (in this case should be form-data ).

Comment: I've removed everything except that I've chosen a PDF document in the body section. Same response...

Comment: please upload your postman screenshot to see what happens there.

Comment: Found my error updated my initial post with the correct setup.